# Conocer la longitud de una lista que tiene un diccionario

Tags: python

Tengo un diccionario que tiene todo el rato la misma estructura. Una `key` y asignada a esta una lista de X variables.

La cosa es que siempre, indistintamente de las `keys` que hayan, todas las listas tendrán el mismo tamaño X.

Por ejemplo `dict = {'k1':('a','b','c'),'k2':('b','c','b'),'k3':('a','c','b')}` en este caso aunque se añadieran más `keys` el valor de las listas siempre será 3.

¿Hay alguna manera directa de saber el tamaño de las listas (realmente solo me basta saber una pues el resto tendrán el mismo valor)?

Yo lo he hecho iterando con un `bucle for`, pero pienso que quizás haya algo más simple ya implementado para los diccionarios.

```
for r in dict.values():
    l = len(r)
    break
```

Así lo que hago es ir a la primera lista y ver su tamaño. El resultado lo tengo, pero es absurdo implementar un `for` para que simplemente haga un ciclo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puedes hacerlo de esta manera:
correccion propuesta por [abulafia](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/7123/abulafia):

```
l = len(next(iter(dict.values())))
```

o una forma mas rudimentaria:

```
l=len(list(dict.values())[0])
```

## desventajas:

Si dict tiene muchos elementos, el `list()` aquí usado forzaría la creación de una lista con todos ellos, y el consiguiente gasto innecesario de memoria, pues en realidad sólo queremos el primero.

Comment: @abulafia exelente respuesta la corregire enseguida!

Comment: @abulafia listo!